# Gridviews/Tables paging. POST, GET or AJAX?

Tags: asp.net, html, design-patterns, gridview

I am building my own GridView in an ASP.NET project

I am drawing out my plans and I was wondering what the best solution is to a simple problem, paging and sorting.

1. The fast and easy way is using submit buttons (or similar) and POSTING the form back. That's also how the ASP.NET gridview works.

   pro:

   - less overhead

   con:

   - backbuttons
2. The second method is using links and the URL with GET requests.

   pro:

   - backbuttons work just fine
   - direct link to certain position

   con:

   - less reusable because of the dependence on url
3. The third method is AJAX

   pro:

   - little overhead

   con:

   - harder to implement

What design/solution would you pick and why?

Am i overlooking some pros and cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add some extra comments to think about.

**-The second method is using links and the URL with GET requests.**
This is the one that you need to use, if your need web spiders (google) knows all the pages of your site, and be SEO friendly. This method have the problem that you can not have viewstate and each time you must render the page that you see on the url parameters with out knowing anything else.

With this case you probably have more problems if you wish to make edit on one line

**-The fast and easy way is using submit buttons (or similar) and POSTING the form back**
This is the method if you won to have many functionality on code behind because with the post back you have all the previous action that you have done, and the viewstate is working and can be used for that. Is not SEO friendly and if you like to make it you need extra code to write on the url just the page that you are now and need to land.

**-The third method is AJAX**
This is the method that must co-exist with the previous and not alone for the case that the browser fails to run javascript for any reason. If you do not care about that, the rest is that this method is also not SEO friendly and you need to make it, is cool, modern, and is a must for modern site, but if you going to make difficult things then you may end up with many issues that must be solved.

To summarize:

```
More than show data ? Post Request : Get Request  ; // ToDo: make it ajax
```

Comment: I also prefer the 'GET request' because of only showing data. Popular websites like GMail, Hotmail, Google, ... also work like this. But A mailbox or Search Engine are not the same as a grid with data about sales etc. Maybe I'm too worried about making the best choice. ps: SEO is not a problem in my case, it's an internal project.

Comment: @BBQ This popular sites that you say, starts with out ajax, and then after years and many money, they develop too much and complex code, spend many resources... I like them also - but they cost in terms of development. Actually your question did not have an answer - you can do any of them, or combination of them. Is just a decision.